# Program / browser extension that sends me an email when someone unfriends me on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a browser extension (ideally Chrome) or program (ideally supporting Windows 7) to send me an email when someone unfriends me on Facebook

Comment: Could you have a notification or do you only want an email?

Comment: I'd much prefer email as it would get "saved" in my Gmail account. Notifications often get inaccessible once I reinstall the browser/OS or change of browser extension.

Answer (score 2):

#### I think this might be what you're looking for: [Chrome Web Store - Unfriend Notify for Facebook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unfriend-notify-for-faceb/ahigpjeolkfgjdaeodlmaceggigbpeoh)

Here is the *slightly* modified <sup>*"(This is an automated translation. Please excuse any grammatical mistakes*)"</sup> description with notable things in bold

> **Get notified, when you lose a friend on Facebook**
>
> Want to know when someone unfriends you on facebook?
> Now you can!
>
> - Seamless Facebook integration
> - **Push-notifications** <sub>*I think they mean in-browser notifications*</sub>
> - Have a try and never miss out if you lost a friend
> - **Data locally stored at your computer**
> - **Our extensions are free of charge** <sub>*Dôh*</sub>

Lifehacker article: [Unfriend Notify for Facebook Sends an Alert When You Lose a Pal](http://lifehacker.com/unfriend-notify-for-facebook-sends-an-alert-when-you-lo-1498827412)

Comment: Thanks but 2 issues: 1. as you can see in the chrome web store the extension make a lot of mistake ("It basically gives you a random list of people. One or two off the people on the list unfriended me. Two or three deleted their facebooks. The rest are still my friends, and did absolutely nothing, and Unfriend Notify just made it all up. Do not waste your time on this." -> I use this extension and I have the same issue) 2. Indeed "Push-notifications" = in-browser notifications, i.e. no e-mail and notifications get inaccessible once I reinstall the browser/OS :/

Comment: Yeah, and besides that, it was originally in another language, and the developers probably didn't want to waste any time, money and resources on a translator (looking at the description)